# Why some method's body does nothing but throw an error?

Tags: flutter, dart

What's the point of these methods, as they are only throwing `UnimplementedError`?

You can see in [this file](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/blob/master/packages/firebase_core/firebase_core_platform_interface/lib/src/platform_interface/platform_interface_firebase.dart), for example

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Updated answer:**

The reason for this case can be found in this comment from the class

> Platform implementations should extend this class rather than
> implement it  as `firebase_core` does not consider newly added methods
> to be breaking  changes. Extending this class (using `extends`)
> ensures that the subclass  will get the default implementation, while
> platform implementations that  `implements` this interface will be
> broken by newly added

The class provides default implementations so current sub classes don't *break* when new methods are added to the base class. If the sub class uses `extend` and the base class provides a default implementation, then the sub class doesn't have to implement the function to compile.

Note that if the base method does not have a body, then the sub class has to implement it regardless of whether `extend` or `implement` were used, which would mean adding new methods is a breaking change for the sub classes.

---

**Old answer:**

This is an `abstract` class that you can find implementations of [here](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/blob/master/packages/firebase_core/firebase_core_platform_interface/lib/src/method_channel/method_channel_firebase.dart) and [here](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/blob/master/packages/firebase_core/firebase_core_web/lib/src/firebase_core_web.dart). I believe the `UnimplementedError`s shown in the base class give a meaningful error in case a method was accessed using an object from a class that did not `override` the function.

So these methods aren't meant to be called as is and should be overridden with appropriate logic as seen in the two links above.

Comment: If all they are doing is telling the base class by throwing an error to implement this function (if that base class hasn't already done so) then why don't they have empty bodies?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Your question got me to look into it again and I updated my answer.

Comment: Updated answer is the **actual answer**.